# Selenium Java can't find same element on second try

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have loop where it interacts with page by changing some settings and saving them and trying head back to same setting page, and on second try it can't find element with id nav-hamburger-menu, although it didnt change after settings has changed. what could be an issue?

Here is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(" Prasisuko ");
            WebElement openMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[id='nav-hamburger-menu']")));
            openMenu.click();
            
            WebElement changeLang = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#hmenu-icp-language.hmenu-item")));
            changeLang.click();
            
            WebElement enUsRadioButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='lop'][value='en_US']")));
            System.out.print(enUsRadioButton.isSelected());

//          // Check if the "en_US" radio button is checked
            if (enUsRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                WebElement deDERadioButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[name='lop'][value='de_DE']")));
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", deDERadioButton);
            } else {
                enUsRadioButton.click();
            }
            
            WebElement spanElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span#icp-currency-dropdown-selected-item-prompt")));
            spanElement.click();

            WebElement aElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#icp-currency-dropdown_19[data-value*='EUR']")));
            aElement.click();
            
            WebElement saveSettingsButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.a-button-input")));
            saveSettingsButton.click();
        }
```

I've tried many ways finding that element, but same thing that on second try it fails

Comment: post the full exception...

Answer (score 0):

Your Question requires more details.
when you say " *and on second try it can't find element with id nav-hamburger-menu,* "

are you able to see one element when you verify through dev tools and script run is failing with an exception?  or your element html values are modified and you are unable to use same locator to identify it uniquely?

You can also post the html snippet for before and after your settings update.

Comment: This is not an answer. Ask your questions in form of a comment.